# PHP convert characters applicable for title tag

Tags: php, html, title, html-entities, entities

In my page I convert lower to uppercase string and output 'em in the title tag. First I had the issue that `&NBSP;` is not accepted, so I had to preserve entities.

So I converted them to unicode, then uppercase and then back to `htmlentities`:

```
echo htmlentities(strtoupper(html_entity_decode(ob_get_clean())));
```

Now I have the problem that I recognized related to a "right single quote". I'm getting this character as `&#8217;` in the title.

It seems that either of the two functions I'm using does not convert them correctly. Is there any better function that I can use or is there something especially for the title tag?

**Edit:** Here is a var_dump of the original data which I don't have influence to:

```
string(74) "Example example example &raquo; John Doe- Who&#8217;s That?&nbsp;"
```

**Edit II:** This is what my code above results in:

[image]

This would happen, if I would just use `strtoupper`:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have HTML entities in your _data_ in the first place?

Comment: If that really is html and you're using it in an html context, why not just use css? `text-transform: uppercase` will handle the display problem and leave you with your original text intact.

Comment: @MarcB: please re-read the question carefully. Like the title tells you, it is about the title tag (`<title></title>`). CSS does not apply to the browsers window title.
@CBroe: unfortunately I don't have any influence on the content. It comes from a different web service which gives me this string, as it is

Comment: Why are you doing all of this? `strtoupper` will work on the original data as well. html does not care about *entities* case so `&NBSP;` will be treated the same way as  `&nbsp;`.

Comment: The only thing i would do, however (if the title is user input), is run `htmlspecialchars` on the input to sanitize it.

Comment: No. When I have uppercase `&NBSP;` in the title, I can still see it as it is in the window title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `strtoupper` will destroy your UTF-8 entity-decoded input because it is not multibyte aware. In this instance, `&#8217;` decodes to the hex-encoded UTF-8 sequence `e2 80 99`. But in `strtoupper`'s single-byte world, the character with code `\xe2` is `â`, which is converted to `Â` (`\xc2`) -- which makes your text an invalid UTF-8 sequence.

Simply use `mb_strtoupper` instead.

Comment: The server our customer is running does not have `mbstring` installed and I unfortunately can't admin it :( I already had several ideas that would require `mb`

Comment: @Julian: Then you will have to accept that there is no way to uppercase non-ASCII characters. For ASCII characters use `strtr` to uppercase `a-z`, which is UTF-8 safe.

Comment: Well then tell them to either get their server upgraded (to what I would consider a de-facto _standard_ already), or make them pay for your development of a custom implementation – or tell them the old _no arms, no cookies_ story …

Comment: I tried your idea in my local PHP active shell. But when I use `mb_strupper` instead, `htmlentities` does not return anything. Is there also a `MB` equivalent for that?

Comment: Can try http://61924.nl/php-utf8/documentation/core/native_utf8_strtolower.html but I'm not entirely sure this is your problem

Comment: @Julian: `htmlentities` automatically works in UTF-8 mode for PHP >= 5.4 (and for posterity, < 5.6). For earlier versions you will have to supply the third argument yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but it might work for you (although I would certainly suggest Jon's solution):

After your `strtoupper()`, you can replace all uppercased HTMLentities this way:

```
$entity_table = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
$entity_table_uc = array_map('strtoupper', $entity_table);
$string = str_replace($entity_table_uc, $entity_table, $string);
```

This should remove the need for `htmlentities()` / `html_entity_decode()`.